# Curl and check for 403 error code

Tags: linux, shell, http, curl, command-line

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
curl "http://google.com" -s -f -o /dev/null || echo "Website down." | mail -s "Website is down" admin@example.com
```

Essentially what I want to do is send myself an email if I get a 403 error.  However, the line above is actually emailing me for any error - 404, 500, etc.

Is there any way to limit this to just 403 errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out :)

```
http_code=$(curl "http://google.com" -s -f -w %{http_code} -o /dev/null)

if ((http_code == 403)); then
    echo "Website down." | mail -s "Website is down" admin@example.com
fi
```